# How can I read image via AWS Lambda python code?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I want to read image file using AWS Lambda python code.

To do this, I use POSTMAN and test it.

I send some image file to my AWS Lambda using POSTMAN and receive response.

And this response's body is like this

"body": "\ufffdPNG\r\n\u001a\n\u0000\u0000\u0000\rIHDR\u0000\u0000\u0001T\u0000\u0000\u0000\ufffd\b\u0003\u0000\u0000\u0000\ufffd\ufffd!\ufffd\u0000\u0000\u0001\u001aPLTE\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\r\u0000\u0000\u0000 \u001c\u001d\ufffd\ufffd\u0000\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\t\ufffd\ufffd\u0000\ufffd\ufffd\u0000\ufffd\ufffd\r\ufffd\ufffd\u0000\ufffd\ufffd\f\ufffd\r\ufffd\r\ufffd\ufffd\r\u0011\u0014\u001d\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\u0017\u0017\u001d\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\uf...

The code for the POST function are as follows

```py
def hello(event, context):

    body = {
        "message": "Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!",
        "input": event


    }

    response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps(body)
    }

    return response
```

So, I think image file has been transfered through event.

Then, I'd like to use it as a local image in this function.

How can use this image file in this 'hello' function?

Comment: Why don't you consider using AWS S3 Buckets for storing the images?

Comment: Because I want to make the system structure as simple as possible.